# join / union two query

Tags: php, html, mysql

first query:

```
  SELECT artikkel_id, liige_id, summa, date, SUM(summa) as papp 
    FROM rent WHERE date < NOW() group by liige_id
```

result :
[image]
second query:

```
SELECT artikkel_id, maksja_id, summa, timestamp, SUM(summa) as peaks
    FROM tulu group by maksja_id
```

result:[image]

in tables maksja_id & liige_id is same.

Point of "join" is, that I can to compare and display liige_id/maksja_id "papp" and "peaks" values and mark in table row with color, when papp < peaks then with red, when = the green etc.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to `join` both the result set saying

```
select xx.artikkel_id, l.nimi, xx.summa, xx.`date`, xx.papp,
yy.summa as yysumma, yy.`timestamp`, yy.peaks
from (SELECT artikkel_id, liige_id, summa, date, SUM(summa) as papp 
        FROM rent WHERE date < NOW() group by liige_id) xx
join (SELECT artikkel_id, maksja_id, summa, timestamp, 
 SUM(summa) as peaks FROM tulu group by maksja_id) yy 
 on xx.liige_id = yy.maksja_id
join liige l on l.liige_id = xx.liige_id;
```

Comment: seems, that's what I want, how I can add the name for liige_id from Table "liige" 
table struktur is 
row 1 liige_id
row2 name

Comment: you can use a column alias saying `column as somename` but I am not really sure if I have understood completely.

Comment: with you example the result is like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lau1bhtgrbk1t54/Screenshot%202016-01-04%2002.34.07.png?dl=0

now I want in my table that liige_id not nr 9 but lige_id display as Margus, and liige is described on table liige ,

liige table struktur liige_id/name

So far I used some inner join commands for that, but right now I can't use that in right combination ;)

Comment: Still not sure I got it completely due to the non English terms you are using. can you post your desired output. So that I know what result you are looking for.

Comment: I posted already result of query, my php table right now looks like : https://www.dropbox.com/s/gynspsin10mi7hv/Screenshot%202016-01-04%2002.54.07.png?dl=0
IN Table perekond value right now is number (9,8,7), what I want to get from liige table https://www.dropbox.com/s/dgqmi5wf7ofrz1i/Screenshot%202016-01-04%2002.57.49.png?dl=0
the name And replace with name 7 = "perekond SIRM", 8 = "perekond VEER", 9 = "Marguse perekond" like that: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1vgpzmkk82dux8p/Screenshot%202016-01-04%2003.04.51.png?dl=0

Comment: See edit in answer and try out the modified query if that helps.

Comment: The last modifie was helpful, the query right now exactly what I want. The final result is here:https://www.dropbox.com/s/i4x5pd2iwqxdua9/Screenshot%202016-01-04%2003.31.36.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Join and union give entirely different results.

Depending on how you want your result to look like here's what you can do

1. Union will give the result of both, giving you 6 records according to your example

   ```
   SELECT artikkel_id, liige_id as maksja_id, summa, date, SUM(summa) as papp 
   FROM rent WHERE date < NOW() group by liige_id
   union 
   SELECT artikkel_id, maksja_id, summa, timestamp, SUM(summa) as papp 
   FROM tulu group by maksja_id
   ```
2. Join will give you the result with 3 records instead of the above 6.

For this you can use @Rahul 's answer

Just like Rahul I think you want the **join**, **not** the **union**.

Comment: Yes join is what I want

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a [SIGN function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_sign) which will classify its argument (such as `xx.papp-yy.peak` as positive, zero, or negative.